# How to run a cron job only once?

Tags: cron

I have a job which runs forever the moment it starts.
So i want to start it only once after entering it into "crontab -e" file and saving it (or) whenever reboot happens.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want a command to run *once* at a later date, use the `at` command.

If you want a command to be run *once* at system boot, the correct solution is to use either:

- system RC scripts (/etc/rc.local)
- crontab with the `@reboot` special prefix (see manpage)

The latter is the only option for a non-root user.

Comment: +1 for mentioning @reboot.

Comment: I would always prefer using /etc/rc.local if possible... I suspect that @reboot actually runs commands on crond startup, not system boot. Subtle but possible difference.

Comment: suppose i entered @reboot "cmd ............." into the crontab file and saved it. Will this command start now? (or) Does it start only after reboot?

Comment: Try it and see :) What you'll probably need to do is put it into crontab, then schedule for immediate execution using `at now`

Comment: Good answer.  I always forget about `@reboot`.

Comment: @MikeyB that is a brilliant way to solve it.Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 9):

You could use at(1) to run a job at some point in the future.  However, if you want to run something on boot and it'll stay running by itself, maybe you want an entry in /etc/init.d/ for it?  That would let you start it on boot.

Comment: You could also use rc.local.  The commands in /etc/rc.local "will be executed *after* all the other init scripts. You can put your own initialization stuff in rc.local if you don't want to do the full Sys V style init stuff."

Comment: Joe: good call.

Comment: How to stop the process which started by at command? (i know kill process id after seeing list of process ids by using "ps command" does this work for "at command" also).Is creating custom scripts easy?

Comment: Yes to both.  All processes can be stopped using `kill` (assuming you've got the permissions to do so, which you do for your own processes).

Making an init script is really easy.  Look in `/etc/init.d/` for a script that isn't very long and model yours after it, or google for `making init scripts (your distribution)`.

Comment: A lot of distros include a skeleton script (`/etc/init.d/skeleton` on openSuSE) that you can adapt for your use.

Answer (score 4):

A job that runs only once and runs forever till you tell it to die is called a "daemon". They are normally started via init scripts in /etc/init.d/.

If your job ends at some point and can be considered a one-off kind of job, then you may want to look at the at command. For instance if I wanted to run the find command at 10PM tonight and only this once I would do:

```
$ at 10PM
at> find /root > /root/find_results.list
at> <EOT>
job 3 at 2010-02-10 22:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the at command

Comment: what will happen when the systems gets rebooted? Do i again need to enter "at command" ?

Comment: The at command entries won't be lost across reboots. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-job-scheduling.html is an interesting introduction to job scheduling

Comment: @Rama Vadakattu: "The at command entries won't be lost across reboots." ...that haven't been executed yet. See **MikeyB's** answer.

Comment: ok i will do more research on this.